# Sharepoint soap request, how to set dropdown fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, soap

I want to post some data into sharepoint list using jQuery and Sharepoint webservices.
The problem is that I've to set some dropdownboxes required in the list, textfields are no problem. How to set them?

Thx for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ;# around the values for the choice(s). Maybe you even need to add a namespace to the fieldname, like this: `<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#FieldName">2;#Choice_Value</SetVar>`

Take a look at [this blog post](http://dotnetstep.blogspot.com/2009/01/batch-update-in-sharepoint.html).

Also take a look at [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) It is big library for working with sharepoint using jQuery.